# (Python 3 / OpenCV) cv2.imwrite returns a Boolean and not the image object

Tags: python-3.x, return, opencv, python

I am trying to edit a color image and return the gray scale of that image. Which I am able to do but I can only get to it by hard coding the name. After a little print statement debugging I found that the return statement I was using in only returning a boolean.

```
def change_to_gray_scale(path):
  color_image = path
  img = cv2.imread(color_image, 0)
  gray_img = cv2.imwrite(color_image.strip(".jpg") + "_colorless.jpg", img)
  return gray_img  # Returns a Boolean and not "new_image_colorless.jpg"
```

What I wanted to do it get it to return the new image but I have had no luck. I have been at this for a few hours now and just might be making a silly little mistake. So while I take a break I thought I would let some other eyes take a look at it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you share the input path(path), you are passing to your function.

Comment: @shubham I use a function to ask for a path from the user. But the image I am using is in the current path of the program file.                                                                           
`def locate_image():
    path = input("What is the location of the image you would like to us? ")
    return os.path.abspath(path)`

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I have just decided to go with a little work around string formatting. CV2 documentation for C says that imwrite returns a bool so I'm just going to assume that is the same for python.

Here is the work around I came up with.

```
image_str = (image_path.strip(".jpg") + "_colorless.jpg")
image_name = os.path.split(image_str)[1]
```

In the future I will put this into function above.